# helgrind reports a race with no conflict - what does that mean?

Tags: valgrind

According to the helgrind docs, a race is reported with two stack traces - one where the race is detected and another where the same location was read/written in a different thread with no before/after relationship.

I have one case (full error below) where helgrind only reports the race location, but no conflict location. What does that mean? This is on a complex codebase, I don't know how to reproduce on simpler code. Normally I see 2 stack traces as expected.

```
==10720== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0x89886CC by thread #2
==10720== Locks held: none
==10720==    at 0x5111BDA: proactor_do_epoll (epoll.c:1816)
==10720==    by 0x5111AD9: pn_proactor_wait (epoll.c:1842)
==10720==    by 0x4EB8CF1: proton::container::impl::thread() (proactor_container_impl.cpp:467)
==10720==    by 0x4EB949B: proton::container::impl::run(int) (proactor_container_impl.cpp:509)
==10720==    by 0x4EB5D51: proton::container::run() (container.cpp:83)
==10720==    by 0x40D2F7: main::$_0::operator()() const (multithreaded_client_flow_control.cpp:267)
==10720==    by 0x40D2B4: void std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (functional:1390)
==10720==    by 0x40D284: std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>::operator()() (functional:1380)
==10720==    by 0x40D178: std::thread::_State_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()> >::_M_run() (thread:197)
==10720==    by 0x613776E: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:83)
==10720==    by 0x4C34A14: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:389)
==10720==    by 0x5E65739: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==10720==  Address 0x89886cc is 44 bytes inside a block of size 1,728 alloc'd
==10720==    at 0x4C30E70: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==10720==    by 0x5329B1E: pn_object_new (object.c:202)
==10720==    by 0x5329E30: pn_class_new (object.c:61)
==10720==    by 0x510F844: new_pconnection_t (epoll.c:697)
==10720==    by 0x510F668: pn_proactor_connect (epoll.c:1217)
==10720==    by 0x4EB742B: proton::container::impl::start_connection(proton::url const&, pn_connection_t*) (proactor_container_impl.cpp:196)
==10720==    by 0x4EB7708: proton::container::impl::open_sender(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, proton::sender_options const&, proton::connection_options const&) (proactor_container_impl.cpp:226)
==10720==    by 0x4EB57F6: proton::container::open_sender(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, proton::sender_options const&, proton::connection_options const&) (container.cpp:97)
==10720==    by 0x4EB58FA: proton::container::open_sender(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, proton::connection_options const&) (container.cpp:52)
==10720==    by 0x40E3C0: sender::sender(proton::container&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (multithreaded_client_flow_control.cpp:80)
==10720==    by 0x40C6DD: main (multithreaded_client_flow_control.cpp:270)
==10720==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify 3 levels at which helgrind remembers the 'past' access for a race:

> --history-level=none|approx|full [full]

The default is full, which means to record a stack trace for each past access. However, the nr of such recorded past stack traces is limited. In your case, probably the conflicting access is too old, and its stack trace was 'cleaned up'.

You might obtain the past stack trace by increasing the amount of recorded past stack traces using

> --conflict-cache-size=N   size of 'full' history cache [2000000]

If you have enough memory, you might try with the max allowed value
(150000000).